# Constructing and arranging boxplot on the basis of the median

Tags: r, boxplot

I have my data in tabular form with variable obvservations in each column, something like this:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   0   0   0   2   0   2
4   182 44  82  73  22  37
76  3   101 15  42  94  15
17  151 102 10  44  2   36
88  32  42  32  79  92  50
30  10  10  121 11  0   64
39  2   25  42  73  15  34
92  13  56  37  21  148 238
31  1   12  366 196 102 55
2   113 141 6   70  89  0
22  53  4   53  119 11  26
37  268 5   7   75  264 
10  2   33  29  40  179 
67  23  61  25  61  168 
111 21  36  32  47  70  
28  17  311 11  21  38  
10  63  52  17  71  15  
72  11  27  67  14  118 
17  84  92  1   58  14  
89  29      85  25  17  
20  8       40  67  95  
23  12      41  40  3   
324 3       13  18  27  
8           23  113 25  
22          3   165 13  
133             63      
12              31      
22              68      
65
```

My eac column has variable number of observations.

Now for a normal boxplot construction I would have done:

```
d1<-read.table("file.txt",header=T)
boxplot(d1,outline=F)
```

but here I want to have my boxes arranged according to their medians and not as per the sequence in which they occur in my data frame.

Any suggesstions?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "boxes arranged by their medians"? Do you mean that the variables should be sorted in the way they are plotted, such that for example the variable with the lowest mean gets plotted first?

Comment: Yes the variable with the lowest median first and so on, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the data.frame prior to plotting by the median. Then `boxplot` will work the way you intended:

```
d1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=";", text=
"a  ;b  ;c  ;d  ;e  ;f  ;g
0  ;0  ;0  ;0  ;2  ;0  ;2
4  ;182;44 ;82 ;73 ;22 ;37
76 ;3  ;101;15 ;42 ;94 ;15
17 ;151;102;10 ;44 ;2  ;36
88 ;32 ;42 ;32 ;79 ;92 ;50
30 ;10 ;10 ;121;11 ;0  ;64
39 ;2  ;25 ;42 ;73 ;15 ;34
92 ;13 ;56 ;37 ;21 ;148;238
31 ;1  ;12 ;366;196;102;55
2  ;113;141;6  ;70 ;89 ;0
22 ;53 ;4  ;53 ;119;11 ;26
37 ;268;5  ;7  ;75 ;264;
10 ;2  ;33 ;29 ;40 ;179;
67 ;23 ;61 ;25 ;61 ;168;
111;21 ;36 ;32 ;47 ;70 ;
28 ;17 ;311;11 ;21 ;38 ;
10 ;63 ;52 ;17 ;71 ;15 ;
72 ;11 ;27 ;67 ;14 ;118;
17 ;84 ;92 ;1  ;58 ;14 ;
89 ;29 ;   ;85 ;25 ;17 ;
20 ;8  ;   ;40 ;67 ;95 ;
23 ;12 ;   ;41 ;40 ;3  ;
324;3  ;   ;13 ;18 ;27 ;
8  ;   ;   ;23 ;113;25 ;
22 ;   ;   ;3  ;165;13 ;
133;   ;   ;   ;63 ;   ;
12 ;   ;   ;   ;31 ;   ;
22 ;   ;   ;   ;68 ;   ;
65 ;   ;   ;   ;   ;   ; ")

d2 <- d1[, names(sort(sapply(d1, median, na.rm=TRUE))) ]
boxplot(d2)
```

Comment: Looks good. At first I thought it should have been (and it could have): `names(d1)[order(sapply(d1,median))]` but then I realized how you were doing it which is just as effective.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but how about trying it with my example data. I am having some problems with my example data. Could you please use my data set to plot the figure. Thank you

Comment: I was reluctant to use your data, as it was unusable with the code you privided. If you read the data in like I do (blanks are coded as NA), then all that changes is to set `na.rm=TRUE` when calculating the median.